# How to process wipefs command output?

Tags: text-processing, uuid, amazon-linux

My command, `wipefs /dev/sdX`, gives the below output:

```
offset               type
----------------------------------------------------------------
0x111                ext4   [filesystem]
                     UUID:  1111111-222222-333333-4444-5555555555
```

---

How to get the UUID value only as output from single command line?

Comment: I never used `wipefs` without the `--force --all` issued as well, is this output _normal_ and universal?

Comment: Please, add your operating system name and version to your question, thank you. At this point we know not if we can use GNU `grep` or BSD `grep`, just examples... You must provide this for any valuable help to come in. Thank you.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak am running  on Amazon Linux ec2 instance

Comment: What is the output of `wipefs --version`?

Comment: are you looking to get the UUID of an existing filesystem? are you sure you want to use `wipefs`, and not e.g. `blkid`?

Comment: @ilkkachu I want to use blkid, but it is not giving uuid

Comment: Can you show us how have you invoked `blkid` and the obtained output?

Comment: @PauloTomé Yes I did https://stackoverflow.com/q/60328702/3317808

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU [`grep(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html), and  your version supports options `-P` or `--perl-regexp`, then its possible to use a positive lookbehind assertion

```
grep -Po "(?<=UUID:  ).*$" <(wipefs /dev/sd)
```

Tests

```
$ cat file
offset               type
----------------------------------------------------------------
0x111                ext4   [filesystem]
                     UUID:  1111111-222222-333333-4444-555555555

$ cat file | grep -Po "(?<=UUID:  ).*$"
1111111-222222-333333-4444-5555555555
```

From [`grep(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) man page

> ```
> -o, --only-matching
>    Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part 
>    on a separate output line.
>
> -P, --perl-regexp
>    Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression (PCRE, see below).  This is highly 
>    experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.
> ```

Regex explanation:

Uses a Positive lookbehind assertion `(?<=UUID:  )` which causes to only print the string after until the end of line `$`.

Comment: `export var=$(sudo wipefs /dev/sdf | grep -Po "(?<=UUID:  ).*$")` and then `mkfs.ext4 -F -U "$var"` gives syntax error

Comment: What is the return value of `echo "$var"`?

Comment: There must be more elegant solution than this + Why did you use Perl expression?

Comment: AFAIK, Perl is a non-standard feature of GNU `grep`, please reformulate the answer to be more audience-acceptable. Thank you.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak, doesn't the answer here start with "if you have GNU grep"? It never claims `-P` would be a standard feature, and its not like the GNU tools, or using their nonstandard features would be especially uncommon. (and if we're talking about standards, `-o` seems also nonstandard.)

Comment: The `cat`  and the `pipe` can be remove at least.  `grep -Po "(?<=UUID:  ).*$" file` without the `cat`  and `pipe`  will have thesame result.

Comment: I would change `"(?<=UUID:  ).*$"` to `"(?<=UUID:  )[[:alnum:]-]+"` to make it more resilient in the face of output format changes from version to version as pointed out in don christi's [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/569005/how-to-process-wipefs-command-output#comment1058177_569012)

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk -F: '$1 ~ /UUID/{print $2}'
```

Comment: man page says _The default output is  subject  to change._ so current answers may not work with the next release. Do it right (no need for post-processing): `wipefs -i -O UUID /dev/nvme0n1p3` ... (add `-n` if needed). OP, it's all in the manual, you know...

Comment: @don_crissti Invalid option `-i` and `-O`